# MinGW: C++ Compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to compile an old C++ code using MinGW om windows 7 (./configure , make ..etc. )
but something goes wrong. I am so sorry if my question is silly but I'm still a beginer! 
No similar error details in other posts. please, any help?

[image]

Comment: Is `g++` even on your path?

Comment: `checking for g++... no` well this is a rather clear signal that the compiler can't even be found in the PATH.

Comment: I've added C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin to the path , is this what you mean?

Comment: What do you get from typing `g++ --version` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I get: (sh: g++ command not found!)

Comment: @Reda: Well, if you can't find `g++`, then `./configure` won't be able to either.

Comment: Thank you Ben. when i type it on cmd.exe i get the version ,i get command not found only when typing it in mingw command prompt! @BenVoigt

Comment: @Reda: Then you need to configure the path that mingw uses.  Often that's in a `etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: @BenVoigt:
C:\Users\XXXX>g++ --version       
g++ (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: `echo %PATH%` from cmd.exe and `echo $PATH` from mingw bash

Comment: @ssnobody you are right. these two pathes are different. how to edit it on mingw bash? echo does not allow me to edit!

Comment: They SHOULD be different. I might have been unclear. I was suggesting you post both paths. We should be able to pick off the path component missing from the bash shell and then you can edit profile or bashrc (as noted above) to add that component in.

Comment: Please consider editing the question for spelling, grammar, and style.  The "dump MSYS" answer is accepted, so perhaps rephrase the question to say we don't care too much about the development environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK here goes...

1. Dump MSYS and MinGW(.org)
2. Download and install [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/).
3. Start the MSYS2 shell, type `pacman -Syu mingw-w64-i686-gcc` or `pacman -Syu mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` (do you want to build a 32-bit or 64-bit thing? You can install both, they live happily side by side). If pacman upgrades the msys2-runtime, close the shell and restart it.
4. Try what you did again, but from the MinGW-w64 Win32/Win64 MSYS2 shell (see your start menu for the shortcuts)
5. Live happily ever after.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the installation instructions for MINGW correctly.

See http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Env Variable "Path": C:\MinGW\bin [If you have MinGW in C:\MinGW].